# staticmethod decorator seems pointless

Tags: python, python-decorators

I was reading about the **`@staticmethod`** in Python when I came across tge following code:

```
class MyClass:
    my_var = 0

    @staticmethod
    def static_method():
        MyClass.my_var += 1
```

I just don't understand exactly why you can write a code like this... Doesn't it defeat the purpose of this method to be static?

I get it that there's also the fact that the first parameter won't be a class/instance reference, but... Still weird to call this decorator like that if I still can access class variables, no?

And if I can access class variables, why everywhere I read about it says that I cannot, even though I just clearly did with the code above? Is it just because I'm doing it wrong?

Comment: 1. Where exactly did you read that you can't access class variables? They are as accessible as instance variables but are shared among all instances. 2. I don't understand how this example led you to believe that the `staticmethod` decorator is pointless. All it does is allowing the method to be callable directly from a reference to the **class**, not **only** from an instance.

Comment: 3. There is no direct link between this decorator and class variables and they are not specifically made to be used together

Comment: That code is bad. You shouldn't ever change class variables, though python won't stop you

Comment: https://youtu.be/PNpt7cFjGsM?t=144
If you look it at this exact timestamp you can see a panel saying that Static Method "can't modify class state"

Comment: You can change class state as long as you have a reference to the class. Here, you have a hard-coded reference to `MyClass`. The fact that the hard-coded reference is inside a static method isn't relevant. The main point is that the static method doesn't provide a reference to the calling class as an (implicit) argument.

Comment: @mousetail Even if I used the decorator '@classmethod', instead?

Comment: @chepner Great, that was where I wanted to go! So this is just bad code and I should avoid getting a Class reference that way, right?

Comment: @VitorTamberlini That would be better, but typically class variables are constants so changing them might lead to unexpected surprises when people assume them to be constant

Comment: @mousetail *"You shouldn't ever change class variables"* Huh? why not? If used correctly there is nothing inherently wrong with modifying class attributes

Comment: It's for sure an opinion question, I was always tough never to do it but apparently that's not a universal guideline, you can override the value in a child class though

Comment: @VitorTamberlini *"Static Method can't modify class state"* That is blatantly wrong

Comment: I use them mainly to put a function in the class' namespace, usually to indicate that it has some relationship to it — but other than that, there's really not much point.

Comment: I think @chepner answered my question, but... You posted as a comment 
If you answer it I can vote as the accepted anser (or anyone that feels like answering hahah)

Comment: @DeepSpace Right? And that's quite bad because this 'Real Python' channel/website has so many good tutorials and made this hideous mistake... I'll give a comment over there as well, then, but thank you for the help y'all! 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea that a static method can't modify class state is based on the idea that the static method doesn't *receive* a reference to the class as an argument like a class method does. However, in this case, a reference to the class is provided as a hard-coded value.

One reason for defining a static method rather than a class method is to guarantee that you modify the attribute of a specific class, rather than a possible subclass.

```
class A:
   my_var = 0

   @classmethod
   def foo(cls):
       cls.my_var += 1

   @staticmethod
   def bar():
       A.my_var += 1


class B(A):
    my_var = 0
```

A call to `B.foo` will modify `B.my_var`, not `A.my_var`. A call to `B.bar` will modify `A.my_var`.